# Java looped Scanner.hasNext() always evaluating to false after first evaluation is false

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm looking to write a method that checks whether user input satisfies the prompt question. For example a prompt "Enter Y or N" could be answered by the user through entering y, Y, n, or N.  If the input is satisfactory the method returns the character entered in uppercase. Otherwise another prompt "Invalid char" will be shown and the scanner checks the next input attempt.

I ran the program and the method checks the first input attempt correctly. However, the problem is that if the first input attempt is wrong and "Invalid char" is shown, ANY subsequent input attempts will be unsatisfactory, i.e. sc.hasNext() in the code below is now always false. As such the program gets stuck in the while loop.

The strange thing is, I ran this exact code a week ago and it worked as intended. If it helps, I'm using the Java N-IDE app for Android.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   verifyInputChar("Enter Y or N", "yn");
  }

  public static char verifyInputChar(String prompt, String acceptedChars){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println(prompt);
  while(!sc.hasNext("^(?i)[" + acceptedChars.toUpperCase() + "]$")) {
     System.out.println("Invalid char.");
     sc.next();
  }
  char input = Character.toUpperCase(sc.next().charAt(0));
  System.out.println(input);
  sc.close();
  return input;    
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regular expression to do this, you aren't reusing a `Pattern` so it doesn't even appear to be an optimization. Instead, I would suggest you simply read your `input` check if there's a match in `acceptedChars` like

```
public static char verifyInputChar(String prompt, String acceptedChars) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(prompt);
    String input = sc.next().toUpperCase();
    while (!acceptedChars.toUpperCase().contains(input)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid char.");
        input = sc.next().toUpperCase();
    }
    char ch = input.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(ch);
    return ch;
}
```